# ListActivity not instantiated via startActivity()

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a ListActivity:

```
public class ContactsListListActivity extends ListActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
. . .
```

When I try to instantiate it like so:

```
Intent selectSelectedContactsIntent = new Intent();
selectSelectedContactsIntent.setClassName("com.aXX3AndSpace.KeepInTouch",
  "com.aXX3AndSpace.KeepInTouch.ContactListListActivity");
startActivity(selectSelectedContactsIntent);
```

(which is the same pattern I'm successfully using elsewhere)

...the Activity (ListActivity, does it make a diff?) is not started.

When that code (startActivity(selectSelectedContactsIntent)) executes, the Debug perspective takes over Eclipse, and in the Instrumentation.class pane I get "Source not found .. the Jar file \android-1o\android.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below"

However, I did this is really the problem, as it runs otherwise and gives me no such grief.

...?

Answer (score 3):

Your app is crashing for some reason. Take a look at the output in logcat and find the stacktrace the system outputs when this happens. That should give you a clue what's going on.

My first completely-random guess: You didn't list the activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I'll also add: If you're calling this within your own application, you're creating the intent in a strange way. The usual pattern is:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Comment: LogCat died. Console says this:

[2011-12-28 20:29:44 - Unexpected error while launching logcat. Try reselecting the device.] device not found
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device not found
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.setDevice(AdbHelper.java:736)
 at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:373)
 at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:372)
 at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiver$1.run(LogCatReceiver.java:100)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: -and: The last line in "Tasks" in Eclipse's Debug Perspective is: "XXX compiler bug in javac 1.5.0_07-164, we need to implement Filterable AutoComplete4.java /ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view line 54 Java Task"

...but I don't know why ApiDemos would be here...

Comment: Sounds like something's strange with your setup. Can you try running "adb logcat" from your terminal? (The ANDROID_SDK/tools directory will need to be in your path.)

Comment: I don't think it's probably with the path, as it has worked fine until just recently.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that the PATH is your problem. I'm suggesting you try the command line logcat tool, since that has less dependencies than the one built into Eclipse.